# How to skip cells while reading an excel file using Apache poi in android?

Tags: java, android, excel, apache, apache-poi

I have this code in my app that uses Apache poi library, but the problem is that he is reading cells that I don't want. Because of that I want to now how to read the cells only starting on row 33. How can I do it?

```
File file = new File(inFileName);
            Workbook workBook = WorkbookFactory.create(file);
            Sheet sheet  = workBook.getSheetAt(0);


            Iterator<Row> rowIter = sheet.rowIterator();
            while(rowIter.hasNext()){

                Row myRow =rowIter.next();


                Cell cell1 = myRow.getCell(0);
                Cell cell2 = myRow.getCell(1);
                ...


                Iterator<Cell> cellIter = myRow.cellIterator();
                while(cellIter.hasNext()){
                    Cell myCell = cellIter.next();

                }

                //bd.addAnimalls(cell1.toString(),cell2.toString());

                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "on inserting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();



            }
```

Answer (score 0):

You may determine the total number of physical rows with `sheet.getPhysicalNymberOfRows()` and use this as upper index limit.
Then, instead of `sheet.rowIterator()`, use index-based rows `sheet.createRow(index)`:

```
for (int i = 33; i < sheet.getPhysicalNymberOfRows(); i ++)
{
    Row r = sheet.createRow(i);
    ....
}
```

Comment: I need another way. Maybe an if statement inside the while loop?

Comment: You may put it whereever you need ) I showed a basic concept how to start reading from specified row index

Comment: but what is the index?

Comment: index == i from `for` loop

Comment: Can you edit using all my code. Im kinda confused how should I put that :/

Comment: because I need Row myROw = rowIter.next to pass the column number I think

Comment: How do you use createRow? I want to pass the column and not create a row?

Answer (score 0):

This is covered in [the Apache POI documentation on iterating over rows and cells](http://poi.apache.org/spreadsheet/quick-guide.html#Iterator). It's well worth reading the documentation!

To iterate from Excel row 33 onwards, which is POI row 32 (POI rows are 0 based), to a maximum of row 1400 (as an example), you'd want to do something like:

```
int rowStart = 33-1; // POI rows are 0 based
int rowEnd = Math.min(1400, sheet.getLastRowNum());
final int MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT = 10; // Minimum number of columns to consider

for (int rowNum = rowStart; rowNum < rowEnd; rowNum++) {
   Row r = sheet.getRow(rowNum);
   if (r == null) {
      // This whole row is empty
      // Handle it as needed
      continue;
   }

   int lastColumn = Math.max(r.getLastCellNum(), MY_MINIMUM_COLUMN_COUNT);

   for (int cn = 0; cn < lastColumn; cn++) {
      Cell c = r.getCell(cn, Row.RETURN_BLANK_AS_NULL);
      if (c == null) {
         // The spreadsheet is empty in this cell
      } else {
         // Do something useful with the cell's contents
      }
   }
}
```